# Dockerfile for Rails app - Permission Denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, docker, rvm, dockerfile

I am attempting to create a docker image of a rails app using rvm (as non-root) and am running into permission errors:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update -q
RUN apt-get install -qy curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y imagemagick --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y curl patch gawk g++ gcc make libc6-dev patch libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison pkg-config libffi-dev

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash app
USER app

RUN gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
RUN /bin/bash -c -l 'rvm install 2.2.1'
RUN /bin/bash -c -l 'rvm use 2.2.1'
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "echo 'gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc' > ~/.gemrc"
RUN /bin/bash -c -l 'gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc'

RUN /bin/bash -c -l 'mkdir /home/app/rails_app'
WORKDIR /home/app/rails_app

ADD Gemfile /home/app/rails_app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /home/app/rails_app/Gemfile.lock

RUN /bin/bash -c -l 'bundle install'

ADD . /home/app/rails_app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD /bin/bash -c -l 'RAILS_ENV=production rails server -p 3000'
```

The image builds fine but when I run the container with `docker run`
     I get the following error:

```
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:367:in `delete': Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /home/app/rails_app/tmp/pids/server.pid (Errno::EACCES)
```

If I add:

```
USER root
RUN /bin/bash -c -l 'chmod -R 777 /home/app/rails_app/'
RUN /bin/bash -c -l 'chown -R app:app /home/app/rails_app/'
USER app
```

The container runs but the rails server did not start and there is nothing in the logs. Executing `/bin/bash` on the running container and trying to start the rails server ends in `rails: command not found` while logged in as app. Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You create a user app, that is good, but your line `USER app` means you do all what follows this line with this nonprivileged user. That is wrong, your line USER... should be just before your CMD command.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression rvm and `bundle install` needed to be ran as non-root as I ran into issues even trying to run this all as root. Is that assumption incorrect? If the gems are installed using root will I be able to access them as non-root?

Comment: Do you need rvm or rvmsudo in order to install?